# Min Max Value in coloumn but with a certain condition

Tags: mysql

I have a MySql table with 3 coluomn : Nip, Bidang and Total. 
I want to count min and max value of total with the same bidang. but i don't want to count min  and max value for all coloumns.

Sample data:

```
NIP    Bidang    Total
1      A         10
2      A         5
3      A         1
4      B         4
5      B         7
6      C         8
7      C         9
```

And the result column:

```
MIN
1
1
1
4
4
8
8
```

Comment: Iam Sory, i can't post my table or picture. My sample tabel Coloumn NIP = 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 , Coloumn Bidang = A A A B B C C, Coloumn Total = 10 5 1 4 7 8 9, and the result column MIN = 1 1 1 4 4 8 8. Thanks

Comment: Edit the question.  Add sample data.  Add the results that you want to get.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply do this:

```
SELECT * FROM 
(
(SELECT Bidang FROM TableName) T1 LEFT OUTER JOIN
(SELECT bidang, MIN(Total) MinVal, MAX(Total) MaxVal
FROM TableName
GROUP BY Bidang) T2 ON T1.Bidang=T2.Bidang
)
```

Result:

```
BIDANG  MINVAL  MAXVAL
A       1       10
A       1       10
A       1       10
B       4       7
B       4       7
C       8       9
C       8       9
```

See result in [**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7d948/2).

**EDIT**

To see the Total column also, add `Total` to first query.

```
SELECT * FROM 
(
(SELECT NIP,Bidang,Total FROM TableName) T1 LEFT OUTER JOIN
(SELECT bidang, MIN(total) MinVal, MAX(Total) MaxVal
FROM TableName
GROUP BY Bidang) T2 ON T1.Bidang=T2.Bidang
)
```

Result:

```
NIP    BIDANG   TOTAL   MINVAL  MAXVAL
1      A        10      1       10
2      A        5       1       10
3      A        1       1       10
4      B        4       4       7
5      B        7       4       7
6      C        8       8       9
7      C        9       8       9
```

See result in [**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7d948/4).

Comment: thanks. but my problem NIP, Bidang and Total also is shown and the value of total always wrong. The result I desire is like this:
[link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0At6v8cxsoOU4dHBnUmx6aEUtdzIwX0hWdlB3UGpPcXc#gid=0)

Comment: in my sql coloumn bidang is write twice, so what solution for this case?

Comment: @user3440030: Replace `*` with `Bidang,MinVal,MaxVal`. Then the result will have only these columns.

Answer (score 0):

```
Select bidang, min(total) MyMin, Max(total) myMax
From tableName
group by bidang

NIP bidang total
1   A      10
2   A      5
3   A      1
4   B      4
5   B      7
6   C      8
7   C      9
```

should return

```
A 1 10
B 4 7
C 8 9
```